# i want to login to my website using phoneNumber and password using asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.NET Web API. I successfully register and login a website using userName and password but now I need to change the default property to PhoneNumber and password to login. From front-end I done what it need but I don't know how to change this property in Web API. But when I tried to login with username and password it login successfully but I want to change it to phoneNumber and password.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
//POST : /api/ApplicationUser/Login
//.FindByNameAsync(model.PhoneNumber);
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.PhoneNumber);
    if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim("UserID",user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_appSettings.JWT_Secret)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
        return Ok(new { token });
    }
    else
        return BadRequest(new { message = "Mobile NO or password is incorrect." });
}
```

it does not show any error because i use angular and it show toaster there and show message mobile number or password is incorrect.

Comment: Sure looks like C# not vb.net. Do tags need correction?

Comment: @Mary its asp.net core

Comment: You mean vb.net looks like that in core?

Comment: @Mary can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you asked for Phone Number when you were registering the user? And also do you have Phone Numbers as annotations in the Login model? If not, do it at first, maybe then it'll work.